# Marketing Cloud SQL Query 1 to many only get result if only 1 record is present in that Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I know a thing or two about SQL Queries, but in this case i can't figure out what to do. So in this case we have a Contact_Salesforce DE where all contacts are in. We have another DE named Placement__c_Salesforce. The relationship between the two is one to many. The Placement DE is where the orders of the contacts are in. I want to make a SQL query which only adds a contact to a new DE when this contact did his first order and NOT get contacts in who already did a few orders.

This is the code as far as i have it:

```
select contact.id as Id
, contact.email as Email
, contact.firstname as FirstName

from contact_salesforce contact

left join placement__c_salesforce placement
on placement.candidate__c = contact.id

where ?????
```

Hope someone can help me.

Cheers

Comment: You can also create a new field in Contact object of type "rollup summary" where you can COUNT the number of orders. Then use this field in your SQL query.

Comment: I know but adding fields to an object is not needed if it's solvable via a SQL query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the SQL [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause.
Assuming I've understood your objective; this should work as your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE contact.id in (
       select candidate__c 
       from [placement__c_salesforce] 
       group by candidate__c 
       having count(1)=1
)
```

In short, this will only return records where contact.id is only found ONCE in `[placement__c_salesforce]`

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i wanted. Your solution did the job. Thanks :)